# .NET Core OData Action Parameter Null

Tags: .net-core, odata

My Odata Action Parameters are not resolving / deserializing.

I am using dotnet core 2.2 to surface an OData controller.

I need to implement an unbounded action.  The action parameter (UserDto userDto) is not being deserialized by the OData routing engine:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [ODataRoute(Routing.Endpoints.UserRoutes.AUTHENTICATE)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate(UserDto userDto)
    {
        var user = await _userService.Authenticate(userDto?.Username, userDto?.Password);

        if (user == null)
            return BadRequest("Username or password is incorrect");

        var dto = Mapper.Map<UserDto>(user);

        return Ok(dto);
    }
```

Here is my configuration:

```
         app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
        {
            var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(app.ApplicationServices);
            odataBuilder.EnableLowerCamelCase();

            odataBuilder.EntitySet<BookDto>(nameof(Book));
            odataBuilder.EntitySet<UserDto>(nameof(User));

            var authenticate = odataBuilder.Action(Routing.Endpoints.UserRoutes.AUTHENTICATE);
            authenticate.Parameter<UserDto>("userDto");

            routeBuilder.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Count().MaxTop(int.MaxValue);
            routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", string.Empty, odataBuilder.GetEdmModel());
        });
```

Here is the UserDto:

```
   public class UserDto
   {
       [Key] public Guid Id { get; set; }

       public string Username { get; set; }
       public string Password { get; set; }
       public string Token { get; set; }
   }
```

When I post:

[image]

The action is resolved by the routing engine - but the parameter does not have the "Username" and "Password" values:

[image]

If I use the `[FromBody]` attribute on the parameter - the "userDto" parameter is null:

[image]

The schema seems correct:

```
<Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="Default">
    <Action Name="authenticate">
         <Parameter Name="userDto" Type="ExampleApi.Dto.UserDto"/>
    </Action>
    <EntityContainer Name="Container">
         <EntitySet Name="Book" EntityType="ExampleApi.Dto.BookDto"/>
         <EntitySet Name="User" EntityType="ExampleApi.Dto.UserDto"/>
          <ActionImport Name="authenticate" Action="Default.authenticate"/>
    </EntityContainer>
 </Schema>
```

I have tried following this:  [Action Parameter Support](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-07-action-parameter-support)

And even Microsofts version (albeit dated):  [Actions and Functions in OData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions)

Been banging my head on this all day...

Comment: I think that Authenticate would be better a simple POST instead of using odata.

Comment: I wish it was that easy.  Using dotnet core 2.2; I cannot use endpoint routing with Odata routing.

Comment: If you don't use odata routing for auth?

Comment: Guess I am not following you.  How do you use both routing types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use simple WebApi attributes only to achieve authentication

```
 public class UserController : ODataController
 {
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("user/auth")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate([FromBody] UserDto userDto)
    {
        return Ok(userDto);
    }
 }
```